# remap keys vim style with alt key

Tags: autohotkey

I want to have vim style navigation by remapping <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> to emulate the arrow buttons.

This is my AHK script:

```
!h::Left
!j::Down
!k::Up
!l::Right
```

The problem is that this script seems to send the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key along with the arrow key.

Eg. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> is sent by AHK.

What's wrong with my script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how your current code is being interpreted, but you can use the `Send` command to send special keys.

```
!h::Send, {Left}
!j::Send, {Down}
!k::Send, {Up}
!l::Send, {Right}
```